# php:process the select tag

Tags: php, mysql

this code run but when test it .. the data not correct i select data from database and i make it in array ad show it id by select tag but when select any id and submit .. example i select 5 and click on submit the record will delete is 2 not 5

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";
$qid="select id from info_user";
$arrayid=array();
$result=mysql_query($qid);
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$arrayid[]=$res['id'];
}
var_dump($arrayid);
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
$id=$_POST['id'];
$q="delete from info_user where id=$id ";
$qq=mysql_query($q);
if($qq){
    echo "you delete record ";
}
else{
    echo "error in deleting";
}}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>delete</title>
</head>
<form action="delete.php" method="post">
<select name="id"><?php for($i=0;$i<count($arrayid);$i++){?>
<option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $arrayid[$i];} ?></option></select> <br />
<input type="submit" name="sub" />     
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: what does the array output?

Comment: I understand English is not your main language, but please try to make easier to read sentences with a . or ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that problem is in value for the options.

Try changing option line  to

```
<option value="<?php echo $arrayid[$i];?>"><?php echo $arrayid[$i];} ?></option></select> <br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<option>` markup is wrong. Make your markup like this;

```
<select name="id">
  <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrayid); $i++) { ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $arrayid[$i]; ?></option>
  } ?>
</select>
```

**Tip:** You'll find debugging easier if you [indent your code.](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB553GB553&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20online%20indent) IDE's generally have this option. [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) is my favourite.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending the ids, you're sending an array key associated to the id.

For instance, assume that: `$arrayid = array(10, 11, 12);`.

This is equivalent to: `$arrayid = array(0 => 10, 1 => 11, 2 => 12);`.

You'll see the options 10, 11 and 12, but you'll send either 0, 11 or 12, because that's what you're setting to the options values:

```
<select name="id">
   <option value="0">10</option>
   <option value="1">11</option>
   <option value="2">12</option>
</select>
```

If you select the option "11", the SQL statement to delete an entry will be:

```
delete from info_user where id=1
```

I did not test this code and I'm assuming the ids are integers, but try it:

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";
$qid     = "select id from info_user";
$arrayid = array();
$result  = mysql_query($qid);
while( $res = mysql_fetch_array($result) ){
    $arrayid[] = $res['id'];
}

if( isset($_POST['sub']) ){
    $id = (int)$_POST['id']; // make sure it's an integer to avoid SQL injections
    $q  = "delete from info_user where id=$id";
    $qq = mysql_query($q);
    if( $qq ) {
        $error = "you delete record ";
    } else {
        $error = "error in deleting";
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>delete</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if( isset($error) ) :
            echo '<p>', htmlspecialchars($error), '</p>';
        elseif( !empty($arrayid) ) :
            var_dump($arrayid);
        endif;
        ?>

        <form action="delete.php" method="post">
            <select name="id">
                <?php foreach($arrayid as $id): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo (int)$id;?>">
                    <?php echo (int)$id; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="sub" />     
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```